# how to diagnose issues in web page and png file via edm

Tags: css, edmx

[Png file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEAOH.png)

I want to ask few questions:
1. What is EDM.
2. How to diagnose issues in a web page and .png file via EDM.

Answer (score 0):

EDM on IT words, can be an acronym for:

- Event Driven Marketing
- Electronic Direct Marketing
- Email Direct Marketing
- Electronic Direct Mail
- Enterprise Data Management
- Electronic Document Management
- Enterprise Data Modeling
- Entity Data Model
- Enterprise Decision Management
- ...

i don't know if i've let some related out.

I don't know in which context you are, and it seems to rare to diagnose issues on a png file using "EDM".

It seems that you're asking some homework question on SO without googling it on the correct ambit.

Anyway, i think you're talking about **EDMX**:

**EDMX** is Visual Studio's "container" for all things about your Entity Data Model.

It contains all the information that is in the CSDL, SSDL, MSL, plus information about the visual layout of the tables in your Visual Studio designer surface.

The EDMX file is converted into CSDL, SSDL, MSL (typically embedded as resources in your assembly) during the build process. You definitely don't have to distribute or copy the EDMX files anywhere for the app to run.

if you are more interested in a code-based approach, you should check out the [code-first CTP for Entity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-released.aspx) Framework which gets by without any .edmx, .csdl/ssdl/msl files at all.

You may need to do a research and ask it properly (i think your question will be highly down-voted)